# How to pass a Java array to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, json, javafx

I have a JavaFX application that shows the location point on Google maps. It is working fine when I pass only variables in javascript. Hhere is the code in JavaFX where I am passing the variables name (lat and lon)

```
  public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude.getText());
                lon = Double.parseDouble(longitude.getText());

                System.out.printf("%.2f %.2f%n", lat, lon);

                webEngine.executeScript("" +
                    "window.lat = " + lat + ";" +
                    "window.lon = " + lon + ";" +
                    "document.goToLocation(window.lat, window.lon);"
                );
            }
        });
```

I want to pass a double array instead of double variable. Here is the javascript function where I am receiving values from Java variable name (x and y)

```
 document.goToLocations = function(x, y) {
        alert("goToLocation, x: " + x +", y:" + y);
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
        marker.setPosition(latLng);
        map.setCenter(latLng);


    }
```

And here is the code example link that i am using [Code Example](https://gist.github.com/chaschev/7481304)

Comment: (JavaScript is one word)

Comment: A solution that came to my mind (I'm not a java developer) is that you can convert the array to string like "[1,2,3,4]" and pass it as a string inside javascript `eval()` method and assign it to a variable there.

Comment: typo error sorry

Comment: (it's ok, but it's good to know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
    List<Double> list = List.of(Double.parseDouble(latitude.getText()), Double.parseDouble(longitude.getText()));
    //Pass list.toString() to the JavaScript function
    //...
}

document.goToLocations = function(values) {
    var x = values.split(", ");
    alert(x);
    alert(x[0]);
    //...
}
```

[List.of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) was added in Java9. For Java version lower than 9, use the following statement:

```
List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(Double.parseDouble(latitude.getText()), Double.parseDouble(longitude.getText()));
```

-OR-

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
list.add(Double.parseDouble(latitude.getText()));
list.add(Double.parseDouble(longitude.getText()));
```

Comment: The method of(double, double) is undefined for the type List

Comment: [List.of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) was added in Java9. I've updated my answer. Feel free to comment in case of any further issue.

Comment: thanks for your answer but google maps stop working when i am adding eval function

Comment: I've updated my answer with another way instead of using `eval`. Feel free to comment in case of any further issue.

Comment: thank you  Arvind Kumar Avinash  , i have modify your code and it works now and your answer helped me a lot thank you

Comment: Do you need to split `values` in the Javascript function? If you just pass `list.toString()`, unquoted, the representation is identical to a Javascript array.

Comment: @James_D - The [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()) method of `ArrayList` creates a string with `,` and *space* between the elements. That is why it needs to be split on `", "` (comma and space) to create a JavaScript array string which does not have space between the elements.

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly the same format for defining an array in Javascript. If you put quotes around the result of calling `list.toString()`, then you pass a single string variable, and you need to split it. But if you don't put quotes around it, you're simply passing an array already, and you don't need to split it.

Comment: I tested and it works fine with simply `webEngine.executeScript("document.goToLocations("+list+")");`, and then the JavaScript function just sees `values` directly as an array.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @James_D for the update. This will be helpful for the OP as well as future visitors.